# Installing .exe package in background within c++ windows service

Tags: visual-c++, installation, package, exe

I have written windows service in VC++ that download files from server as per received file list in XML. File list contains 1) .net framework setup .exe package name 2) msi package name. 
Requirement is to install these files in background, here I could perform silent installation for .msi package using msiexec and CreateProcess but for .exe package (ie. for .net framework installer) I can't do it using CreateProcess in background. How I can perform .exe installation in background within windows service application.

Answer (score 0):

Most exe installs allow a silent installation, but have own and different parameters. You have to read their documentation and/or google.
Every .NET framework has slightly different parameters, but some work with "/q /norestart" for example. 
E.g. google for "Aaron Stebner's WebLog".

Comment: Thanks Philm!! Yes, DotNetFramework itself provides option for silent installation. I could install it by providing "/q" to CreateProcess. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure. If you would vote up, it would be kind.